# How to dynamically open/close ul and li every x?

Tags: php

I am trying to build a php loop which generates a html navigation with years like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    1900
    <ul>
      <li>1901</li>
      <li>1902</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    2000
    <ul>
      <li>2001</li>
      <li>2002</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Php I am trying:

```
foreach (range(0, 1000, 100) as $number) { ?>
    <ul>
        // Here I should be checking 
        // if it is year 1942 or 2000 or 1080 
        // and place ti correctly
        <?php echo $number; ?>
    </ul>
<?php }
```

The above works, gives me a new `ul` every 100.

But I don't understand how I should set my `php` to open a new `<ul>` and `<li>` if we have "*sub years*" inside the century itself, also I should be checking what year is it that I am outputting in order to have it in its right `<ul>` or `<li>`

Comment: I see only HTML, no PHP code to debug/help.

Comment: loop in centuries, and do a subloop (for years) inside

Comment: @Manikiran because I am looking for a logical/verbal help mostly, something which helps me get the idea right before to start writing the code.

Comment: @Jeff but that will let me make so many loops no? I mean 10 loops with 10 years each for every century, is that what you meant?

Comment: oops, I corrected myself: loop in centuries (19,20,21..), and a subloop for years (00-99)

Comment: @Jeff so maybe I should use a php range like foreach (range(0, 100, 10) as $number) {... as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you need:

```
<?php
$start_year=1900;
$end_year=2100;
for($year=$start_year;$year<=$end_year;$year++){
    if($year%10==0) //Replace 10 (for decades) with 100 (for centuries)
    {
        if($year!=$start_year){
            echo '</ul></li></ul>';
        }
        echo '<ul><li>'.$year.'<ul>';
    }
    else{
        echo '<li>'.$year.'</li>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: yes sort of thanks, check my updated question as I have a simpler php range to open/close every 100, yet what if I have 1942 for example?

Comment: Now i'm more confused than before. If you could tell us how you got those years (i mean like if you get them randomly or in a order), and how you want to display (though you presented a html, doesn't have clarity).

Comment: I get them via custom fields when I loop to retrieve the content, they are dynamic

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695693/how-to-check-a-value-against-current-range-in-foreach

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<ul>";
  for ($century=1900; $century <= 2000 ; $century =$century + 100) {
    echo "<li>". $century;
      echo "<ul>";
      for ($year = $century; $year < $century + 100; $year++) {
        echo "<li>". $year . "</li>";
      }
      echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
  }
echo "</ul>";
```