# How to display a years list ordered by century

Tags: php

I have an array of years like this:

```
[1500, 1946, 1923, 1258]
```

and I'd like to display them ordered by century (displaying the corresponding century as well) this way:

```
<ul>
  <li>1200
    <ul>
      <li>1258</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1500</li>
  <li>1900
    <ul>
      <li>1923</li>
      <li>1946</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note that years of the same century are children of the same `il` century item. Also, if one of the years matches with the century itself, I only want to display the parent `il`.

My idea was to use a range but how do I check if the value is more or less than the current range and **nest** a `ul` or `li` correctly based on the year? - Not even sure if it's the correct approach tho, this below isn't fully working but it's an idea:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $value_1 = "1942";
    $value_2 = "1230";
    foreach (range(0, 3000, 1000) as $number) {
        echo $value;
        if ($value < $number) { ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo $value... ?>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

**I'll put it in plain words:**

I have a cms where the user can select a year, could be 1942 or 1230. Now i get these years in front end and I would like to build a dynamic navigation out of them as per the html above

Comment: Hmm... sorry, I can't figure out what exactly you're asking, even after reading several times. Could you give an example?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas In the cms you choose a year, 1942 or 1290. Now These 2 numbers are within 1900 and 1200 centuries. So I need to first of all output the main century, secondly to insert a sub ul with the corresponding year. Is it clear?

Comment: I've read this plenty of times and still makes no sense. You want to output the century (ie: 1200) and then the exact date (ie: 1243) nested in a `ul`?

Comment: @KDOT yes exactly. The thing is it needs to be dynamic as those years could be any within a range of 3 thousands centuries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have another way to do that. This works also if there are more than one year in the same century.

```
<?php

$yearsArray = [1500, 1946, 1923, 1258];
$centuryHash = [];

$yearsArray = array_unique($yearsArray);
sort($yearsArray);

foreach ($yearsArray as $year) {

    $currentCentury = floor($year/100)*100;

    if(!$centuryHash[$currentCentury]){
        $centuryHash[$currentCentury] = [];
    }

    if($currentCentury != $year){
        $centuryHash[$currentCentury][] = $year;
    }
}

//echo "<pre>" . print_r($centuryHash,1) . "</pre>";

echo "<ul>";

foreach ($centuryHash as $century => $centuryYears) {
    echo "<li>" . $century;

    if($centuryYears){
        echo "<ul>";

        foreach ($centuryYears as $year) {
            echo "<li>$year</li>";
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    }

    echo "</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
```

Here you can see the content of `$centuryHash`:

```
Array
(
    [1200] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1258
        )

    [1500] => Array
        (
        )

    [1900] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1923
            [1] => 1946
        )

)
```

And here you can see the result:

- 1200

  - 1258
- 1500
- 1900

  - 1923
  - 1946

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. Works perfectly

Comment: Answer shouldn't be marked, if the year is above the year 50, it returns the higher century. Ie, 1788 would return century 2000 not 1000. @rob.m

Comment: I am just trying now with my real case and see

Comment: @KDOT mm any idea of how we could resolve that?

Comment: yeah my answer lol - added new working one @rob.m

Comment: @rob.m My fault! Fixed it

Comment: @KDOT didn't see you've updated it, let me try now

Comment: @rob.m Just update this line: `$currentCentury = floor($year/100)*100;`

Comment: @KDOT nice, just tested it with real data and yes it works. before 1760 was going under 1800 while now it's correctly going into 1700. Thanks a lot

Comment: @rob.m You are welcome ;) and sorry for the error!

Comment: performance is slower, but nice answer :) @nanocv

Comment: @nanocv when we have 1500 but no child (1501), it is creating twice 1500 as per main 1500 + child 1500. We should simply say has child? Ok create a nested list, no child? Just print the li

Comment: @rob.m I didn't understand this well. If you have `$yearsArray = [1500]`, do you only want to show the '1500 ul parent'?

Comment: @nanocv yes exactly. I mean If we only have a full number like 1500, we simply show the parent as there are no childs while now it is doing Parent. 1500, Child 1500. This shouldn't happen unless we had 1501 then yes it will be a child of 1500

Comment: @rob.m Fixed. I added the results for you to check it. You just have to add this condition: `if($currentCentury != $year)`

Comment: @nanocv almost there, it is still creating an empty nested ul

Comment: @rob.m Fixed again! Just update the whole `foreach ($centuryHash as $century => $centuryYears){...}` in your code ;)

Comment: superb! It's all working fine now, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128546/discussion-between-rob-m-and-nanocv).

Comment: @nanocv what if we insert twice 1500? It is repeating the values, can we check any how and don't repeat if it is already there?

Comment: @rob.m Updated it! Just add this line before the array sort: `$yearsArray = array_unique($yearsArray);`

Comment: @nanocv perfect! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to round the year to the nearest century to be able to match which year belongs to which century. I added a dynamic max century, if you want to sort the array from min-max year just add that.

*See it working in detail at [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/0Eu4p), or see it working like below at [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/prmon).*

---

```
$years = ['3333', 3689, '3000']; // can be type string or int
$nav = [];

foreach($years as $year) {
    foreach(range(0, round(max($years), -3), 1000) as $century) {
        if(floor((int)$year/1000) * 1000 == $century) {
            $nav{$century}[] = (int)$year;
         }
    }
}
```

---

**Output:** `[3000]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(3333) [1]=> int(3689) [2]=> int(3000) }`

---

This code is pretty procedural, you could renovate this and create a class. Something like this:

```
class Year {
    const PLAIN = 1;
    const ARRAY = 2;

    private $_years = [];

    public function append($year, $type) {
        if($type & self::PLAIN && !is_array($year)) {
            $this->_years[] = $year;
            return $this;
        } else if($type & self::ARRAY && is_array($year)) {
            $this->_years = $year;
            return $this;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Unknown type.');
        }
    }

    public function fetch() {
        return $this->_years;
    }
}

class CenturyConversion {
    public static function parse(Year $years) {
        $nav = [];
        foreach($years->fetch() as $year) {
            foreach(range(0, round(max($years->fetch()), -3), 1000) as $century) {
                if(floor((int)$year/1000) * 1000 == $century) {
                    $nav{$century}[] = (int)$year;
                }
            }
        }
        return $nav;
    }
}
```

Which can be used in two ways, with an Array or with a single year. The methods support type int and type string. This is how to add years manually:

```
CenturyConversion::parse((new Year)->append(1992, Year::PLAIN)->append('1365', Year::PLAIN));
```

This is how to add years in an array:

```
CenturyConversion::parse((new Year)->append([1992, 1365, '2010'], Year::ARRAY));
```

**Summary of the parse code:**

Firstly, we take a numeric input of the years and find the max value inside the array. We then round the max value to the closest thousand so we know where to stop checking and where to start. Then we loop through each year checking its century, we do this by checking the years closest century by rounding it *down* to the nearest thousand.

---

*See the OO styled code working at [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/2B7RG).*

Comment: i'm not sure why i keep having error, what is that "..."  for?

Comment: It is for **[unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)**, it's a new-ish thing in PHP 5.6+ I think but it should work without the `...`. Just remove it if does not work with it because `max()` supports arrays. @rob.m

Comment: I updated the question with a nice OOP design for you and removed the unpacking since it was unecessary. Hope it helps. @rob.m